# relayRemotePushNotificationPayload: method is not working in Sinch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, voip, sinch

Sometimes in my device, we are not able to initiated call.

We are using Pushkit for Call Notification .

So while other user call , we are getting notification through **pushRegistry:didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:forType**

after getting sinch payload we are using below method for relaying payload

```
id<SINNotificationResult> result = (id<SINNotificationResult>)[_client relayRemotePushNotificationPayload:sinchinfo];
```

Now Sometimes , we are getting result from above method , but respective method for **localNotificationForIncomingCall:** and **didReceiveIncomingCall:** is not called. 
So that we are unable to show incoming call.

However outgoing call is working perfectly fine.

We have checked below things

1)**Since Client** is initialized and is not NULL

2)Payload of Notification is proper as we are getting **SINNotificationResult** object from which we have found **callid** for that payload

**Note :** If we are reset device settings , then it will again start working proper.

Comment: Hi weird, what do you mean with reset device settins?

Comment: It means to reset device.Settings > General > Reset > select Erase All Content and Settings.

Comment: Please check caller's device date time and recipient's device date time. It should be set to "Set Automatically". If that works then you don't need to "Reset" device settings all the time.